# Magento form validation

Tags: magento

Can anyone give the complete form validation classes used in magento?

Comment: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/magento-validation-class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you go this url its contains the all classes related with for validation.

http://shivakumariyer.blogspot.com/2011/03/magento-form-validation-text-validation.html